# Как разместить кнопки по вертикали?

Tags: java, swing

Как разместить кнопки по вертикали?

Код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JButton button = new JButton("1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `GridLayout`

---

`GridLayout(строки, столбцы, промежуток (ширина), промежуток (высота))`

промежуток - расстояние между компонентами

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 0));
        frame.setContentPane(panel2);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("1");
        panel2.add(button);
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        panel2.add(button2);
        
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        panel2.add(button3);

        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```